# php date format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to insert the current date from a php form into a database.

My query is:

```
   $sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', 'date()')";
```

This produces the following: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 which obviously isn't right.

Can anyone recommend how to get this to display the correct date/time?

Also, I need it in the following format: yyyymmddhhmmss - Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: The most universal solution is always going with UNIX_TIMESTAMP. When you store your date in this format you can do anything with it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but is very important: Make sure that you never insert PHP variables directly into your SQL query. Always escape them using *mysql_real_escape_string($your_variable)*.

Comment: Hi, How would I go about doing this? On the database side, the field is set to a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @slosd - Thanks for the advice! I'm going to insert this when I am finished. For now I'm just concentrating on getting the queries to work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use php's function `time()` or mysql's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` this is an `int(11)` and used like so:

```
INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', UNIX_TIMESTAMP --
```

Then you create a visual timestamp from php using the `date()` function.. during your loop in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL `NOW()` function:

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', NOW()";
```

Comment: Of course - if field is not DATETIME it's better to use the format from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', 'date(dmy)')";
```

or

```
$time = date('Ymd g:i');
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', " .$time . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', '$date')";
```

Comment: Note OP's question: "I need it in the following format: yyyymmddhhmmss"

Comment: when selecting it back from DB you can convert it to any format you like

Comment: Hi Denis, should I set the field in my database to something other than TIMESTAMP for this to work? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using DATETIME type in MySql, but it should work correctly with TIMESTAMP too. Maybe you dont even need to generate date in PHP, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with TIMESTAMP read this for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the PHP Manual regarding the use of date():  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

So for your needs it would be something like:

```
$date = date("YmdHis");
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', '$date')";
```

Also you might take into account the advice from Fabrik. Using UNIX timestamp is probably the most reliable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your `date` column is actually of mysql DATETIME type.

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO orderDetails (compName, package, cost, date) VALUES ('$companyName', '$package', '$cost_record', NOW())";
```

should do it.

You can store it in DATETIME type (you'll see it as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)and then format it to `yyyymmddhhmmss` when you SELECT it out of the database:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s') FROM orderDetails
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @fabrik May I ask why you added the `` in my second sql string when it was already tabbed in? I'm still new to this so am I missing some formatting convention?

Comment: While it's surrounded by `s it wasn't parsed as code snippet. Now edited again it's fine.